# A matrix to form a shorter vector from a given vector by discarding some elements of the latter.

Tags: matrices

I will try to explain by an example:

Given: A 16x1 vector $ V = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p,]^T$ and four 9x1 vectors $R_1,R_2,R_3$ and $R_4$.

Required: Four 9x16 extraction matrices $\textbf E_1 \textbf E_2, \textbf E_3$ and $\textbf E_4 $, such that

$R_1=\textbf E_1 V$ is $[a, b, c, e, f, g, i, j, k]^T$

$R_2=\textbf E_2 V$ is $[b, c, d, f, g, h, j, k, l]^T$

$R_3=\textbf E_3 V$ is $[e, f, g, i, j, k, m, n, o]^T$

$R_4=\textbf E_4 V$ is $[f, g, h, j, k, l, n, o, p]^T$

Background:
The vector V above is the column-concatenated form of a 4x4 matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & e & i & m\\
b & f & j & n\\
c & g & k & o\\
d & h & l & p\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The $R_i$ vectors are column-concatenated forms of the 3x3 matrices extracted from the above 4x4 matrix.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are $9 \times 16$ matrices each of whose rows consists of all zeros with a single one. I'll work out $E_1$. See if you can do the rest.

$\left[ \begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right]$

Comment: Thanks indeed! The data I need to work on, has |V|>60,000 and I have to construct over sixty E matrices. I am hoping to find a method to form the E matrices in some automated way. I am familiar with Matlab.